# How to count duplicates in column Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I use this rule to filter all rows where column num is unique. So I remove the duplicates:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=["num"], keep=False)
```

Also the same I do with column age:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=["age"], keep=False)
```

How to show result it another table with statistic of deleted elements like this:

```
Duplicates num(total)  Duplicates age (total)
1                      18
```

Thank you for answers, one remark is:

```
NUM AGE
1        18
2        18
3        18
4        20
```

As result I need to get:

```
NUM AGE
4        20
```

And extract duplicates (NUM value column) to list Python for further insertion to db
`duplicatesNums = [1,2,3]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For new DataFrame call [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) per columns in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), count `True`s by `sum` and for one row DataFrame convert `Series` to `DataFrame` with transpose, also `rename` columns:

```
d = {'num': [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2],
      'age': [10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 98, 99, 102]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print (df)
   num  age
0    1   10
1    1   10
2    1   10
3    1   11
4    3   11
5    1   98
6    2   99
7    2  102

f = lambda x: f'Duplicates {x} (total)'
df = (df[['num','age']].apply(lambda x: x.duplicated(keep=False))
                       .sum()
                       .rename(f)
                       .to_frame()
                       .T)
    
print (df)
   Duplicates num (total)  Duplicates age (total)
0                       7                       5
```

Alternative solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({f'Duplicates {x} (total)' : [df[x].duplicated(keep=False).sum()] 
                    for x in ['num','age']})
   
print (df)

   Duplicates num (total)  Duplicates age (total)
0                       7                       5
```

EDIT: For test non duplicated rows use:

```
df1 = df[~df['AGE'].duplicated(keep=False)]
print (df1)
   NUM  AGE
3    4   20
```

For get duplicated values by coumn `NUM` in list use:

```
duplicatesNums = df.loc[df['AGE'].duplicated(keep=False), 'NUM'].tolist()
print (duplicatesNums)
[1, 2, 3]
```

If `NUM` is index:

```
print (df)
     AGE
NUM     
1     18
2     18
3     18
4     20

duplicatesNums = df.index[df['AGE'].duplicated(keep=False)].tolist()
print (duplicatesNums)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: @George - also added new one in part `EDIT`

Comment: How to us this: `duplicatesAges = df.index[df["AGE"].duplicated(keep=False)].tolist()` but to check if `AGE` in existing set `{18,19,22}`? To fill duplicatesAges

Comment: what is ouput from `duplicatesAges = df.index[df["AGE"].duplicated(keep=False)].tolist()` ? and if test with `{18,19,22}` what is expected ouput?

Comment: Sorry for disinformation. I need to iterate rows and check if column is equals = "no" then extract value from column "AGE" to the set Python.

Comment: @George - then use `out = set(df.loc[df['col'].eq('no'), 'AGE'])`

Comment: @George - is possible edit question? Not sure if understand.

Comment: Thank you ! Helped me!  Only last remark should I use this syntax?

`errors["ages"] = df.loc[df['AGE'].duplicated(keep=False)].sum()` to fill count of wrong ages into dict `errors` by key `ages`

Comment: @George - You are close, need ouput of column `AGE`?  then use `errors["ages"] = df.loc[df['AGE'].duplicated(keep=False), 'AGE'].sum()` - added `,'AGE'`

Comment: Why this does not work for me (: I try to fill `names` in dict if custom function return False:

`report["names"] =  df.loc[df["NAME"].apply(checkName), "NAME"].count()`

As result I expect: `report["names"] = {total: 1, indexesRows: [1,2,3]}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244993/discussion-between-george-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) in [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), with [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html) to count the values:

```
df[['num', 'age']].apply(lambda c: c.duplicated(keep=False).sum())
```

dummy example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'num': list('AABCDD'), 'age': list('112345')})
df[['num', 'age']].apply(lambda c: c.duplicated(keep=False).sum())
```

output:

```
num    4
age    2
dtype: int64
```

###### extra question:

```
# identify duplicates
mask = df['AGE'].duplicated(keep=False)
# get indices
ids = mask[mask].index.to_list()
# [0, 1, 2]

# filter DataFrame
df2 = df[~mask]
#     NUM  AGE
#  3    4   20
```

Comment: Thank you a lot , what if I also extract value from column where duplicate or from another column by name?

Comment: @George I'm not sure I follow, can you provide an example?

Comment: `NUM AGE
1        18
2        18
3        18
4        20`

As result I need to get:

`NUM AGE
4        20`

And extract duplicates (NUM value column) to list Python for further insertion to db
`duplicatesNums = [1,2,3]`

Comment: @George that's quite a different question, you can use `df.drop_duplicates('AGE', keep=False)` or, to get the ids: `mask = df['AGE'].duplicated(keep=False) ; ids = mask[mask] ; df[~mask]`, also added as edit